# Summarize with custom function while calling values from outside of group

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to summarize multiple columns using `summarize_at()` with a custom function. The part I'm stuck on is the function `ssmd()` is meant to take a vector of values from the group established by `group_by()` and another vector of values from outside this group.

In the example below, `x` should be a vector for each set of values by `Month` (varies according to the current group), and `y` should be a fixed set of values for `Month == 5`.

```
# custom function
ssmd <- function(x, y){
  (mean(x, na.rm = TRUE) - mean(y, na.rm = TRUE)) / sqrt(var(x, na.rm = TRUE) + var(y, na.rm = TRUE))
}

# dataset
d <- airquality

# this isn't working - trying to find the difference between the mean for each Month and the mean of Month 5, for columns Ozone, Solar.R, Wind, and Temp
d %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(Ozone:Temp), funs(ssmd, x = ., y = .[Month == 5])) %>%
  ungroup()
```

At the moment, this gives the following error: `Error in mean(y, na.rm = TRUE) : argument "y" is missing, with no default`. So I think I have a syntax error, in addition to being stuck on how to access values from outside the current group.

The expected output is a data frame with one row for each Month and one column for each variable (Ozone, Solar.R, Wind, and Temp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues :

1) When you are referring to `Month` in `funs` it is only for that group and not entire dataframe

2) 1) Can be resolved using `.$Month` but you don't have access to entire column in `summarize_at` to subset only those values where `Month == 5`.

However, you don't need that custom function, you can take `mean` of all columns for each `Month` and then subtract the values from each column where `Month = 5`.

```
library(dplyr)

d %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(Ozone:Temp), mean, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Ozone:Temp), ~.  - .[Month == 5])

# A tibble: 5 x 5
#  Month Ozone Solar.R  Wind  Temp
#  <int> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     5  0       0     0      0  
#2     6  5.83    8.87 -1.36  13.6
#3     7 35.5    35.2  -2.68  18.4
#4     8 36.3    -9.44 -2.83  18.4
#5     9  7.83  -13.9  -1.44  11.4
```

---

To use `ssmd` function in the updated post we can do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

named_info <- d %>% select(Ozone:Temp) %>% names()

map(named_info, function(x) d %>% group_by(Month) %>% 
                     summarise_at(vars(x), ~ssmd(., d[[x]][d$Month == 5]))) %>%
    reduce(inner_join, by = 'Month')
```

Comment: Can you give an example how you use `phenoDist::ssmd` function normally and how to use it for your use case?

Comment: Sorry, I think introducing phenoDist unnecessarily complicates things... I made a custom function that better reflects my use case. I'd appreciate it if you took another look.

Comment: @holastello No, there are always better/different ways to do things as I already showed in my original answer. However, I have updated the answer to do it your way. Hopefully, it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to fix your syntax error, but I proposed a workaround here. This summarizes the data as monthly mean for each column, and then just subtract the first value, which is the mean of May.

```
library(dplyr)

d <- airquality

d1 <- d %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(Ozone:Temp), list(~mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  ungroup()

d1[-1] <- lapply(d1[-1], function(x) x - x[1])

d1
# # A tibble: 5 x 5
#   Month Ozone Solar.R  Wind  Temp
#   <int> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     5  0       0     0      0  
# 2     6  5.83    8.87 -1.36  13.6
# 3     7 35.5    35.2  -2.68  18.4
# 4     8 36.3    -9.44 -2.83  18.4
# 5     9  7.83  -13.9  -1.44  11.4
```

Comment: @holastello Please ask a new question and provide reproducible example that can represent the real-word data and function.

Comment: apologies, I tried to make a minimally reproducible example but I guess I stripped it down a bit too far. I edited the function to make it better reflect my use case.